# manually assigning weights, biases and activation function in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to build a neural network with nn.module in pytorch. I want to implement custom weights, biases and activation function.
with input value=5 and first layer weights= [[0.2, 0.3]] and second layer weights= [[1.5],[2.5]], first layer bias= 2 and second layer bias=3 and activation function y=x^2 the output value should obtain 2220.765625 but my code doesn't calculate this value. could you please help me to correct this code?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()  
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=2)
        self.output = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=1)
        self.bias1 = torch.tensor([[2.]])
        self.bias2 = torch.tensor([[3.]])
        

    def act(self, x):
        return x**2

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act(self.fc1(x)) + self.bias1 
        x = self.act(self.output(x)) + self.bias2

        return x

    def weights_initialization(self):
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.fc1.weight.copy_(torch.tensor([[0.2, 0.3]]))
            self.output.weight.copy_(torch.tensor([[1.5],
                                                   [2.5]]))
 

net = NeuralNet()
input_data = torch.tensor([[5.]])
output = net(input_data)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `weights_initialization` method after `net` object is created. Also, set the `bias` inside the linear layers to `False` when manually adding `bias` values. There were also a few other fixes in the following codeL

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()  
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=2, bias=False)
        self.output = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=1, bias=False)
        self.bias1 = torch.tensor([[2.]])
        self.bias2 = torch.tensor([[3.]])
        

    def act(self, x):
        return x**2

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act(self.fc1(x) + self.bias1)
        x = self.act(self.output(x) + self.bias2)

        return x

    def weights_initialization(self):
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.fc1.weight.copy_(torch.tensor([[0.2],
                                                [0.3]]))
            self.output.weight.copy_(torch.tensor([[1.5, 2.5]]))
    

net = NeuralNet()
net.weights_initialization()
input_data = torch.tensor([[5.]])
output = net(input_data)
print(output)
```

Comment: you are welcome. It would be great if you can upvote and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer worked well. I sent a positive feedback to it  but I can't upvote your answer because I haven't enough reputation.